# Joining related tables

Tags: join

I have two tables:

Parent:

```
ItemID     StartDt    ChildItemID
3          1/17/2013       1
```

Child:

```
ItemID    StartDt     EndDt
1         1/1/2013    1/15/2013 
2         1/3/2013    1/17/2013 
3         1/17/2013   1/21/2013
```

I want to find all the Items that have a parent and I want to find the end date of the parent and the start date of the child.

e.g.

```
ChildItemID   ParentItemID    ParentEndDt     ChildStartDt 
3                   1         1/15/2013       1/17/2013
```

How would I write the SQL query?

Comment: what db are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want childless parents a simple inner join will work for you

```
SELECT
   c.ChildItemID,
   c.ParentItemID, 
   c.ParentEndDt,
   c.ChildStartDt 
FROM 
    Parent p
    INNER JOIN Child c on p.ItemId = c.ParentItemID
```

I'm assuming that you can use this ANSI syntax on most RDBM systems